# Не работает перегрузка true, false в LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, перегрузка-операторов

Есть класс Abonent, в котором я перегрузил true и false. Когда в классе Program я пишу следующее

```
Abonent[] arr = new Abonent[n];

// Тут заполняю массив

var arr1 = from p in arr
                   where p
                   select p;
```

То пишет, что не удается неявно преобразовать Abonent в bool. Но когда пишу

```
if(arr[0]){ }
```

то все работает. В чем может быть проблема?

Класс Abonent:

```
public class Abonent
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Sname { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Balance { get; set; }
        public int Intern { get; set; }
        public int Nintern { get; set; }
        public static Abonent operator +(Abonent ab, int C)
        {
            Abonent ans = ab;
            ans.Balance += C;
            return ans;
        }
        public static bool operator true(Abonent ab1)
        {
            Abonent ab = ab1;
            if (ab.Balance >= 10*ab.Intern + 5*ab.Nintern) return true;
            return false;
        }
        public static bool operator false(Abonent ab1)
        {
            Abonent ab = ab1;
            if (ab.Balance >= 10 * ab.Intern + 5 * ab.Nintern) return true;
            return false;
        }
        
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return $"ID: {Id}, Name: {Name}, Surname: {Sname}, Balance: {Balance}, Intern: {Intern}, Not Intern: {Nintern}";
        }
    }
```

Comment: что такое `Abonent`? Код класса в студию. + вы создаете массив, но ничем его не заполняете.

Comment: @tym32167 Массив я заполнил в программе, просто решил не вставлять здесь его заполнение.

Comment: надо было `operator bool` перегружать

Comment: вы определяете true и false операторы, но у вас нет `public static implicit operator bool(Abonent ab1){...}`

Comment: Спасибо, заработало.